# Error "database compatibility level is not supported." while import MSSQL db

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sqlproj

I try to import db schema (MSSQL2008) by Visual Studio 2015 using SqlProj. There are two database to do.

DevDb ver. 10.50.**4000** <- I log with Windows Credentials
TestDb ver. 10.50.**6000** <- I log with sql's user

Compability level 100 for both dbs is "100".

For first everything goes fine, but for second db error occurs.

> "The server version or database compatibility level is not supported."

There is no logs, any entry in EventLog. Mayby I should install something plugin for VisualStudio to handle litter newer version?

Comment: What is the compatibility version of the ***database***. Not the server version which you have provided.

Comment: @CraigYoung:I updated my post

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, then I'm at a loss. The only thing I can suggest is that since you're not up to date on your dev SQL service packs, you might similarly be missing latest VS service packs?

Comment: Does the database you are importing into already exists? If so, what is the compatibility level of that?

Comment: Yes, databases exists. As I wrote above, compability level is "100" on both dev and test db.

Comment: @Jacek That's not what David was asking. Check compatibility level on the source database and target database. Your question suggest that the DevDb and TestDb are both source databases. If that's not the case, you need to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @CraigYoung There is little misunderstood :) Both db are sources. At first I check import on my own dev pc. Everything pass. After I try to do the same on test db (used by team members), but there error occurs...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just ran into this one myself importing a 2008 database into VS 2017.

To start, make sure the project is set for the database version you're using.

- Go to Project -> Properties ...
- Pick the correct Target Platform
- Hit Database Settings, and go to Miscellaneous
- Verify your Compatibility level
- Save these changes (Control + S)
- Then - CLOSE THE PROJECT. I closed VS completely
- Open everything back up.

Your changes should have taken effect, allowing you to import the database.